# Newbie: express pass object array to pug

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, pug

please help me with the following problem:

I try to pass an array of objects to pass to pug.

The array is defined with:

```
...
let subDirs=[
  { name: 'subDir1', files: [ 'static/subDir1/file1.jpg' ] },
  { name: 'subDir2', files: [ 'static/subDir2/file1.jpg' ] },
  { name: 'subDir3', files: [ 'static/subDir3/file1.jpg' ] }
]
...
```

Express renders the object array with:

```
...
res.render('index', { title: 'title', subDirs: subDirs })
...
```

In the pug-file I try to access the objects in the array with the following lines:

```
...
doctype html
html(lang='en')
  head
    title title
    meta(charset='utf-8')
    meta(name='viewport' content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1')
    link(rel='stylesheet' href='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css')
    script(src='https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js')
    script(src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.16.0/umd/popper.min.js')
    script(src='https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js')
  body
    .container
      h2 List
      ul.list-group
        each subDir in subDirs
          li.list-group-item p subDir.name
...
```

The list shows the string "subDir.name" again and again... :(

I have difficulties to catch the point.

Please help.

Thanks for any help in Advance.

Regards

Andreas

Answer (score 0):

According to the [Pug documentation](https://pugjs.org/api/getting-started.html) in order to evaluate the subDir it looks like you need to wrap it in `#{}`

I haven't used Pug before so this is just from a cursory glance at the docs, but if you change

```
li.list-group-item p subDir.name
```

to

```
li.list-group-item p #{subDir.name}
```

I believe it should render as expected

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use [interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html) in order to render the value of the `name` property. If you want to wrap it in a paragraph, you'll need to be sure to indent that too (or use inline [tag interpolation](https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html#tag-interpolation)).

These would all be valid approaches:

```
// string interpolation
each subDir in subDirs
  li.list-group-item
    p #{subDir.name}

// using equals
each subDir in subDirs
  li.list-group-item
    p= subDir.name

// tag interpolation and string interpolation
each subDir in subDirs
  li.list-group-item #[p #{subDir.name}]

// tag interpolation and using equals
each subDir in subDirs
  li.list-group-item #[p= subDir.name]
```

Personally, I prefer the first two in most cases—but they're all equivalent.

Answer (score 0):

thank you for your quick help. It's working now.

I ever hoped not to ask questions that could be solved by reading the documentation. Sorry for that.

Thank you again for your help.

Regards

Andreas

Comment: I wrote in the first line of this anwer "Hi Leshawn and Sean" but the first line got dropped when I posted the answer. Sorry for that too...